# android send pic httppost with json object

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json

How can I put everythig inside the json object?

I'm send pic to my server, but the server answer with 422 because he want an json object like this:

```
parameters: {"spot": 
                   {"description"=>"descriptionblabla", "title"=>"titleblabla" ..... , "photos_attributes" => {"0"=> "ref"=> thefile} }}
```

and I'm sending this:

```
  Parameters: {"title"=>"titlebla", "description"=>"descriptionbla"}
```

api token found 1075, user_id: 2189
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 44.5ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 21.6ms)

```
String token2= mPreferences.getString("auth_token","");

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("x-auth-token", token2);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", sglimagepath);



                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("nuova foto3");
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\""+ lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("proviamoci2");
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                /*dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + sglimagepath +"\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);*/

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
```

I fixed my issue, I wrote here how I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352017/android-send-file-httppost-to-server

Comment: You are not sending "Parameters". Nor are you sending JSON. Nor are you sending a picture. What does 442 mean?

Comment: mean "Unprocessable Entity" is like he receive everythig like above but he want the json object called "spot" and after all the Parameters... The whole log is: api token found 1081, user_id: 2189
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 46.4ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 25.7ms).....I don't know how I can put before the object and after all the parameters.....

Comment: There is no json in your code. So start with creating a json object or json array. After that you make json text of it and send that.

Answer (score 1):

Like how you @greenapps said wasn't there any Json, I'm still having the problem but is another now so I wanted write how I fixed the problem relative to the error that I had (422 error).
I'll post the code below:

```
String token2= mPreferences.getString("auth_token","");

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                //create json object
                try {
                    spot.put("title", "titolo1");
                    spot.put("latitude", "1");
                    spot.put("longitude", "1");
                    spot.put("address", "antani");
                    spot.put("country", "IT");
                    spot.put("shot_level", "pro");
                    spot.put("photo_attributes",photo_attributes);
                        photo_attributes.put("0",attributes);
                            attributes.put("description","Nesciunt dignissimos qui non. Beatae optio eveniet quis..");
                            attributes.put("our_policies","1");
                        /*photo_attributes.put("1",attributes);
                            attributes.put("description","Nesciunt dignissimos qui non. Beatae optio eveniet quis..");
                            attributes.put("our_policies","2");*/

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Convert json to hashmap
                HashMap<String, String> attributesmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject attributesObject = new JSONObject(attributes.toString());

                HashMap<String, String> photo_attributesmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject photo_attributesObject = new JSONObject(photo_attributes.toString());

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject spotjObject = new JSONObject(spot.toString());


                Iterator<?> keys = spotjObject.keys();
                Iterator<?> keys2 = photo_attributesObject.keys();
                Iterator<?> keys3 = attributesObject.keys();

                while( keys3.hasNext() ){
                    String key3 = (String)keys3.next();
                    String value3 = attributesObject.getString(key3);
                    attributesmap.put(key3, value3);
                }
                while( keys2.hasNext() ){
                    String key2 = (String)keys2.next();
                    String value2 = photo_attributesObject.getString(key2);
                    photo_attributesmap.put(key2, value2);
                }
                while( keys.hasNext() ){
                    String key = (String)keys.next();
                    String value = spotjObject.getString(key);
                    map.put(key, value);
                }


                File file = new File(sglimagepath);
                try {
                    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String postURL = upLoadServerUri;
                    post = new HttpPost(postURL);

                    //FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
                    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                    ContentBody con =new StringBody(map.toString());
                    //ContentBody con2 =new StringBody(photo_attributesmap.toString());
                    //ContentBody con3 =new StringBody(con.toString()+con2.toString());
                    //post.setEntity(se);
                    reqEntity.addPart("spot", con );
                    //reqEntity.addPart("image", fileBody);

                    post.setHeader("x-auth-token", token2);
                    post.setEntity(reqEntity);
                    HttpResponse response2 = client.execute(post);
                    HttpEntity resEntity = response2.getEntity();
                    if (resEntity != null) {
                        Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```